# How to bind List to my repeater in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, list, repeater

```
public class Post
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string body { get; set; }
   public List<Comments> comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comments{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string author { get; set; }
   public string text { get; set; }
}

My data layer returns the data I need:
List<Posts> post = (List<Post>)myDataLayer.GetPostAsList();

post has just one post in it even though it is a List.
```

I have 2 repeater controls. 
The first is the posts repeater.
The second is the comments repeater which is outside the Posts repeater.

How can I pull the `List<Comments>` out of Posts and bind to the Comments repeater?

Comment: Are you sure, comments repeater is *outside* the posts repeater? If yes how do you expect comments to be displayed? I ask because regarding to you classes design, comments are related to posts and usually displayed right after post.

Comment: Alex, For simplicity in asp.net/html, I have 2 separate repeaters. But I load the post object that has the comments List.

Comment: Since I am using automatic properties, I am having hard time pulling\getting the Comments list from post.

Comment: Maybe, you meant that comments repeater should be **inside** the posts repeater?

Comment: That will be if I can't get the Comments from post object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPosts">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- markup for posts here-->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptComments">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- markup for comments here-->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The thing left is to bind data:

```
protected override void DataBind()
{
    var posts = myDataLayer.GetPostAsList();
    // if there is at leat one post
    if (posts.Any())
    {
        rptPosts.DataSource = posts;
        rptPosts.DataBind();

        // you mentioned that there should be only one post in the list
        var comments = posts.First().comments;
        rptComments.DataSource = comments;
        rptComments.DataBind();
    }
}
```